# Plotting density function with specific values

Tags: r, plot

I would want to plot a probability density function where

```
if 0<x<0.7 y=0.3    
if 0.7≤x<1 y=0.2    
else y=0.
```

`X` represent probability and `y` density.

How could I do it?

Comment: It's not really going to be a PDF since that would require that the integral over the domain of the distribution be unity.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider it a mixture of two uniform distributions.

```
x <- seq(-0.5, 1.5, 0.01)

y1 <- dunif(x, 0, 1)*1
y2 <- dunif(x, 0, 0.7)*0.7    

y <- y1*2 + y2*1

plot(x, y, type="l")
```

[image]